# GPUImageLookupFilter (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse, filter, gpu

I am using a GPU Image Library in my android Application. The library can be found [here](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage).
You can apply a filter on an image using this code:

```
Uri imageUri = ...;
mGPUImage = new GPUImage(context);
mGPUImage.setFilter(new GPUImageSobelEdgeDetection());
mGPUImage.setImage(imageUri);
mGPUImage.saveToPictures("GPUImage", "ImageWithFilter.jpg", null);
```

But i want to apply a custom made filter so i went to the [documentation](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage/blob/master/README.md) of the library but it had no instructions showing how can i use GPUImageLookupFilter.

I need to get a detailed explanation of how can i use the GPUImageLookupFilter methode.

More Info: This is a port of the [iOS GPUImage Library](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
.
.
.

GPUImageLookupFilter lookUpFilter = new GPUImageLookupFilter();
lookUpFilter.setBitmap(bitmap2);  // second bitmap to add

Uri imageUri = ...; // image uri for first bitmap
mGPUImage = new GPUImage(context);
mGPUImage.setFilter(lookUPFilter);


mGPUImage.setImage(imageUri);
mGPUImage.saveToPictures("GPUImage", "ImageWithFilter.jpg", null);
```